# parse xml string response in grails

Tags: xml, groovy

response xml text is :

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MMP><MERCHANT><RESPONSE><url>http://XXXXXXx/asdasd/asdsd/as</url><param name="ttype">QEQW</param><param name="tempTxnId">155411</param><param name="token">v22mM1NmwpHCKLp%2FZJC%2B7PUKASXr2aS01JPi2ZXDqT0%3D</param><param name="txnStage">1</param></RESPONSE></MERCHANT></MMP>"
```

I want to parse this xml text in grails/groovy. How do I iterate through all the elements to fetch the data of a particular element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [XMLSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper) to read the xml.

Here is some example code for your posted xml:

```
def response = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

// accessing a specific element
println response.MERCHANT.RESPONSE.url
// iterating through a collection
response.MERCHANT.RESPONSE.param.each{println it}
// searching for specific elements
println response.MERCHANT.RESPONSE.param.find{it.@name == 'ttype'}
```

Comment: Im getting this error as i directly place the reponse object,              ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - No signature of method: groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (java.io.ByteArrayInputStream) values: [java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@1e5c475]
Possible solutions: parseText(java.lang.String), parse(java.io.File), parse(java.io.InputStream), parse(java.io.Reader), parse(java.lang.String), parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)                        def feed = new XmlSlurper().parseText(resp)
println response.MERCHANT.RESPONSE.url;

Comment: The code to get reponse is this where im getting the response as xml, def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://XXXXXXx');

def resp = http.get( path: '/asdasd/asd/ad', 
      query:[login:'asd', pass: 'asdasd',ttype:'NBFT',prodid:'NSE',amt:50,txncurr:'INR',txnscamt:0,clientcode:'007',txnid:12345,custacc:1234567890,date:'27/06/2011'],
      contentType : XML,
      headers : [Accept : 'application/xml']
    )

Comment: As the errror message describes, `parseText()` is the wrong method to parse an `ByteArrayInputStream`. Use the `parse()` method of the `XmlSlurper` or convert the stream into a string.