# How to read multiple rows in XML in groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
    <!--  generator=Moneycontrol XML FEED Generator  --> 
 <rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Moneycontrol Business News</title>
        <description>Business News from Moneycontrol.com</description>
        <link>http://www.moneycontrol.com</link>
        <lastBuildDate>Tue, 07 Aug 2012 10:50:03 +0530</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>Moneycontrol.com</generator>
        <image>
            <url>http://img1.moneycontrol.com/images/top2010/moneycontrol_logo.jpg</url>
            <title>Moneycontrol Logo</title>
            <link>http://www.moneycontrol.com</link>
        <description>Feed provided by Moneycontrol.</description>
        </image>
        <item>
        <title>Expect prices to range between Rs 35-40/kg: Sakthi Sugars</title>
        <link>http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/expect-prices-to-range-between-rs-35-40kg-sakthi-sugars_741216.html</link>
        <description>&lt;img src=&quot;http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2012/m/M-Manickam-aug7-190.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;M Manickam&quot; title=&quot;M Manickam&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;75&quot; height=&quot;75&quot; align=&quot; left&quot; hspace=&quot;5&quot;/&gt; M Manickam, managing director of Sakthi Sugars says, he expects the sugar prices to range between Rs 35-40 per kilogram.</description>
        <pubDate>Tue, 07 Aug 2012 10:32:01 +0530</pubDate>
        <guid>http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/expect-prices-to-range-between-rs-35-40kg-sakthi-sugars_741216.html</guid>
        </item>
        <item>
        <title>Maruti factory riot sounds alarm bells for industry</title>
        <link>http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/maruti-factory-riot-sounds-alarm-bells-for-industry_741130.html</link>
        <description>&lt;img src=&quot;http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/2012/m/maruti_unrest.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;Maruti factory riot sounds alarm bells for industry&quot; title=&quot;Maruti factory riot sounds alarm bells for industry&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;75&quot; height=&quot;75&quot; align=&quot; left&quot; hspace=&quot;5&quot;/&gt; Hiding in his office near New Delhi as workers armed with iron bars and car parts rampaged through the factory, Maruti Suzuki supervisor Raj Kumar spent two terrified hours trying to comprehend the warzone his workplace had become.</description>
        <pubDate>Tue, 07 Aug 2012 08:02:02 +0530</pubDate>
        <guid>http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/maruti-factory-riot-sounds-alarm-bells-for-industry_741130.html</guid>
        </item>
        <item>
        <title>New base price will push call rates up 49 p: COAI</title>
        <link>http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/new-base-price-will-push-call-rates49-p-coai_741067.html</link>
        <description>&lt;img src=&quot;http://www.moneycontrol.com/news_image_files/Telecom_new2_190.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;New base price will push call rates up 49 p: COAI&quot; title=&quot;New base price will push call rates up 49 p: COAI&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; width=&quot;75&quot; height=&quot;75&quot; align=&quot; left&quot; hspace=&quot;5&quot;/&gt; Telecom industry body COAI today claimed that the Rs 14,000 crore base price fixed by Cabinet for auction of telecom spectrum will lead to 37-49 paise per minute increase in call tariffs.</description>
        <pubDate>Mon, 06 Aug 2012 22:49:35 +0530</pubDate>
        <guid>http://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/new-base-price-will-push-call-rates49-p-coai_741067.html</guid>
        </item>
    </channel>
 </rss>
```

I wanted to read the multiple rows in the xml file got from a partuclar link which contains multiple  tags, wanted to loop through the whole xml data and fetch each records and insert into database.

Comment: Isn't this almost the [exact same question that you asked last month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534958/parse-xml-string-response-in-grails)?

Comment: no its different as the previous one was parsing xml response as string

Comment: So what is the response in this case?  You are vague in your question...

Comment: thanks for your help @tim_yates as i got the solution from ur reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (as an example) to print the title of each item:

```
 new XmlParser().parseText( xml ).channel.item.each {
   println it.title.text()
 }
```

If you have the xml as a String.  If it is not a String, you'd [want to use](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#parse%28java.io.File%29) one of the 3 forms of `parse` instead of `parseText`